# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! (WebScraping)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

While scraping at [URL](https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain) for the website's data update ***'TIMESTAMP'***,pandas is not able to parse the timestamp value.
However it does fetch the complete raw data fine.
How to filter for the timestamp?

```
**Try_1**  
updateTime = pd.DataFrame(rawdata['records']['timestamp'])  
Output:ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

**Try_2**  
 updateTime = pd.DataFrame(rawdata['records']).get(['timestamp'])  
Output: updateTime = none

**Try_3**  
 updateTime = pd.DataFrame(rawdata['records']).get(['timestamp'],default='Timestamp Not Fetched')  
Output: updateTime = Timestamp Not Fetched   

**RAWDATA**   
  url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'  
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept':'application/json'
    }   
    session = requests.Session()  
    request = session.get(url, headers=headers)  
    cookies = dict(request.cookies)  
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()   
    rawdata = pd.DataFrame(response)
```

[image: Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rawdata` is already a DataFrame, you don't need to call `pd.DataFrame`:

```
>>> rawdata['records']['timestamp']
'06-Jan-2023 12:23:23'

>>> pd.Timestamp(rawdata['records']['timestamp'])
Timestamp('2023-01-06 12:23:23')
```

If you really want a DataFrame, use:

```
updateTime = pd.DataFrame([rawdata['records']['timestamp']])
#         Enclosed with --^                             --^
print(updateTime)

# Output
                      0
0  06-Jan-2023 12:23:23
```